# CSS custom style not taking effect

Tags: css, html, ionic-framework, sass

I have the following **HTML**

```
<label class="item formulario item-input item-floating-label" ng-class="{'has-error': registroForm.nombre.$invalid && registroForm.nombre.$dirty, 'valid-lr': registroForm.nombre.$valid && registroForm.nombre.$dirty}">
                        <span class="input-label">Nombre</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" ng-model="vm.nombre" 
                               pattern="[A-Za-z'áéíóú ]+"
                               ng-minlength="2"                                 
                               ng-maxlength="30"
                               required>
                    </label>
```

I need to set the following style:

```
label.item.formulario {
    border-style: none none solid none;
    border-color: darkblue; 
}
```

But the custom style is not taking effect. If I remove my custom name ".formulario" from my CSS selector and also from the class list in my HTML, the style works perfect **BUT** it modifies the wholes label with an item class. I just need to modify a specific label, this is the reason what I'm trying to create a custom class.

What's wrong?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: *"If I remove my custom name ".formulario"the style works perfect"* if you remove that from your CSS selector or from the class list in your HTML?

Comment: I've just edited my question

Comment: It sounds like you have other CSS for `.formulario` that is overriding. Have you looked in your dev tools to see if any CSS is overriding it?

Comment: Nop. Also I changed the name for avoid this kind of problem

Comment: Can you reproduce this somewhere and link me to it to see?

Comment: Now I create a custom scss for this specific view so I set the sytle only in that scss but not working

Comment: Or include all of the code you're using in your post so that it reproduces the problem for us?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142025/discussion-between-faustino-gagneten-and-michael-coker).

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested it here and the style does take effect :
https://jsfiddle.net/8eo8crz1/

```
label.item.formulario {
    border-style: none none solid none;
    border-color: darkblue; 
}
```

If you want to have a unique custom style for each label, you'll need to use an id instead of a class (or in addition to the classes you're using).

Comment: You can also use a class for a unique style, not just id

Comment: If the style won't be repeated and will be applied to only one element, You'd better use an ID and not a class.